# efficient algorithm for comparing two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, matrix, sentence-similarity

I'm building a similarity matrix of a list of items.
The naive approach is to iterate the list twice, but this needlessly will compare A:B *and* B:A when they're the same.

```
for A in items:
   for B in items:
      if A==B: continue
      sim[A][B] = calc_sim(A, B)
```

is there a simple way to only calculate half of the values?
I could put a skip in there like

```
if sim[B][A]: continue # already calculated in other direction
```

But still the iteration is happening.
Effectively I just want to iterate through the top or bottom half of the grid:

[image: sim matrix]

There are some [similar Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475466/efficient-algorithm-for-comparing-and-iterate-through-two-large-arrays), but nothing with a canonical answer.
This seems like a basic CS algo question!

Comment: Is this about Python?

Comment: the above is pseudo-code. i am writing python in this case tho yes but it's more about an algorithm language independent. I know i can use libraries like sklearn for NearestNeighbot but more interested in the raw algo for myself. added a python tag anyway

Comment: Use `break` instead of `continue`?

Comment: @superbrain I think you could be right! simplest is best haha.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
import itertools

for a, b in itertools.combinations(items, 2):
    sim[a][b] = sim[b][a] = calc_sim(a, b)
```

Comment: oh thanks for pointing this out. it's a bit python specific, but itertools is a great toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `calc_sim(A, B) == calc_sim(B, A)`, you could try this:

```
for A in range(0, len(items)):
   for B in range(A, len(items)): # Replace with A+1 if you don't want the case A == B
      # Remember A and B are indexes, so change code accordingly
      result = calc_sim(items[A], items[B])
      sim[A][B] = result # Copy result to both A,B and B,A as they are equal
      sim[B][A] = result
```

However actually both algorithms are `O(n)` n<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Now `calc_sum` will get *indices*, not the actual *values*

Comment: Yeah, I made a note about it, but then @abc has a better answer.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544844/2180316

Comment: `for B in range(A,` ... nice trick, this will effectively cut off one half of the mirror image.

Comment: Its not very Pythonic, you should use the itertools method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just a general algorithm to reduce number iterations, you can limit the range of the inner loop

```py
for i, A in enumerate(items):
   for B in items[:i]:
      sim[A][B] = calc_sim(A, B)
```

But if you are looking for Python-specific optimization, it would be much better to use numpy vectorization. For example, if `calc_sim(a, b)` computes squared difference between `a` and `b`, then it can be vectorized the following way:

```py
import numpy as np

list = [1, 2, 3]
array = np.array(list)
sim = np.square(array[:,np.newaxis] - array)
```

```
[[0 1 4]
 [1 0 1]
 [4 1 0]]
```

Comment: it's actually an array of word vectors I'm using to do the comparison. Can `np` be made to take any comparison function and apply it to a grid in that way, or just np built-ins like `np.square` ?

Comment: @dcsan It can be done if the vectors have the same length. I think that this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array But if the vectors have different lengths, than numpy is unlikely to be able to handle them, as long as they are not preprocessed in some way